# Use foreach over MatchCollection hangup in one app but not another

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

I just encountered an weirdest issue in my coding life, I use a [code highlight library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/FastColoredTextBox_.aspx) in an project that I attempted to customize the SQL code viewer. I took a sample form from the sample and put it into the project, and the form hangup at startup. But the very same example runs fine in the sample project comes with the library. The two are both Winform app. And furthur investigation shows me that the code hang up in the library itself, not the code that is in the sample form

```
var matches = regex.Matches(text);
foreach (Match m in matches) // Here it hangup
{
    ...
}
```

But the very same spot runs as snappy as it can be when I run the sample winform app comes with the library. I'm so confused. I think something as basic as Regex should perform the same no matter in which application. The text is not long, just a few hundreds characters. And the regex is the same. I didn't do anything differently other than that I extract the sample form and put it into my project and call it.

Can someone help me or point me to the right direction?

Comment: What happens when you put run the same regex over the same text in a separate test app? What exactly do you mean by “hangup”? Does it use up your CPU?

Comment: is the sample code uses the same .NET framework version?

Comment: Also post your regular expression (and text, if it is not too big). Did step through the code in the debugger? If so, when did it hang - the first entry into the loop, or on one of the matches?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that something "as basic as regular expressions" would perform equally across implementations is wrong for several reasons:

- Regular expressions aren't regular anymore. Modern additions like backreferences, lookaround expressions, recursive pattern matching etc. have greatly expanded on the basic regular expressions from decades ago.
- There are [dozens of regex flavors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) out there, each implementing a different subset of features, many interpreting the same tokens in different ways. For you, the difference between JavaScript (client-side) and .NET (server-side) regexes is probably the most relevant one, and boy, are those two different.
- There are many parameters that can be set (like whether the dot matches newlines or not) which will affect how a regex matches (and can affect performance a lot), and you need to ensure that those parameters are set correctly.

Most probably, you're running into a problem called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). A "hang" inside the library itself is often caused by this. To find out if that's the case and how to correct it, we need to see your regex, an explanation of what you're trying to do with it and/or a sample of your input text that it's having problems with. Please edit your question and add those details.